# Can I use my own templating engine and parameters with everyauth?

Tags: node.js, authentication, everyauth

Everyauth documentation and sample app mentions:

```
// a string of html; OR the name of the jade/etc-view-engine view
.loginView('login.jade')
```

Note login.jade has some everyauth specific parameters which everyauth seems to magically provide:

```
  #login
    label(for=everyauth.password.loginFormFieldName) Login
    input(type='text', name=everyauth.password.loginFormFieldName, value=email)
  #password
    label(for=everyauth.password.passwordFormFieldName) Password
    input(type='password', name=everyauth.password.passwordFormFieldName)
  #submit
    input(type='submit') Login
```

The view in my app where users log does a variety of things, not all of which are related to logging in. As a result, I don't wish to configure my login view at the same time as everyauth.

**Can I omit .loginView() and set up the view that displays the login form later?**

Thanks.